# Redirect based on url arguments (via PHP or cPanel)

Tags: php, apache, amazon-s3, cpanel

I just started using Amazon S3 to host static files (images, videos, etc.).
For accessing the uploaded files, temporary links are created.
A temporary link looks like this one:

```
http://zeebit.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-logo.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXEHEYSBDWAAXVVA&Expires=1346888760&Signature=B%2BS%2FlUoRXno3UfSqf9Ua0RuCcBc%3D
```

What I want is to serve these file through my url, something like this:

```
http://s3.mydomain.com/zeebit/stackoverflow-logo.png/AKIAIXEHEYSBDWAAXVVA/B%2BS%2FlUoRXno3UfSqf9Ua0RuCcBc%3D
```

I know I can redirect requests to `http://s3.mydomain.com` to the Amazon url via PHP (for example), but I don't want the address bar to change.
I can create a .htaccess to transform the url to the Amazon url, but as I know .htaccess can't redirect to external resources.

So, how can I solve this?

Comment: Deleted my answer as i wasn't aware that s3/aws/whatever acted as a CDN and not just a file store (I'm not familiar with amazon's offerings). Since its a CDN then there is no way to do what you want, you must direct the user to the CDN url.

Comment: I was tackling this problem myself a month or two ago. If you are wanting to use expiring URLs, then there is no real option to retain your own (sub)domain as the location of the file - it has to be within the `s3.amazon.com` domain. And *.htaccess* can be used to redirect to external resources (with a change of hostname, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions:

### .htaccess Solution #1 - Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^s3\.  # Hostname starts with "s3."
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f  # Not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d  # Not a directory
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$    http://$1.s3.amazonaws.com/$2?AWSAccessKeyId=$3&Expires=$5&Signature=$4 [R=302,L]
```

NOTE: Your initial desired URL was missing the "Expires" value, so the above would work for URLs formed like so:

```
http://s3.yourdomain.com/[[S3_Bucket_Name]]/[[S3_Filename]]/[[AWSAccessKeyId]]/[[Signature]]/[[Expires]]
```

So:

```
http://s3.mydomain.com/zeebit/stackoverflow-logo.png/AKIAIXEHEYSBDWAAXVVA/B%2BS%2FlUoRXno3UfSqf9Ua0RuCcBc%3D/1346888760
```

would redirect to

```
http://zeebit.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-logo.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXEHEYSBDWAAXVVA&Expires=B%2BS%2FlUoRXno3UfSqf9Ua0RuCcBc%3D&Signature=1346888760
```

### .htaccess Solution #2 - Redirect

Whilst being a less flexible solution than the above, you could put the following into your *.htaccess* file

```
redirect 302 /s3/ http://zeebit.s3.mydomain.com/
```

Using this rule, requests for

```
http://yourdomain.com/s3/stackoverflow-logo.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXEHEYSBDWAAXVVA&Expires=B%2BS%2FlUoRXno3UfSqf9Ua0RuCcBc%3D&Signature=1346888760
```

Would basically retain everything after `/s3/` and simply replace everything preceeding it with the Amazon S3 location.

```
http://zeebit.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-logo.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXEHEYSBDWAAXVVA&Expires=B%2BS%2FlUoRXno3UfSqf9Ua0RuCcBc%3D&Signature=1346888760
```

Comment: I created a subdomain s3 on my domain. This subdomain points to public_html/s3 folder. Inside this folder I placed the .htaccess file suggested by you (in solution #1). If I access the url: http://s3.yourdomain.com/[[S3_Bucket_Name]]/[[S3_Filename]]/[[AWSAccessKeyId]]/[[Signature]]/[[Expires]] with the parameters changed of course, just a 404 error is shown up.

Can you test this on your server and tell me if it worked? Thank you!

Comment: OK, the problem is that, when some of the signature variables are decoded, they include slashes. Playing around with ideas to resolve that now, although, honestly, the more I am looking at this the less purpose I can see it serving.